# CardView Click state not working

Tags: android, material-design, android-cardview

I would like to change the color of Card Item whenever user does tap on any of the item, but nothing happens.. why ?

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="9dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="0.01dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:foreground="@drawable/card_foreground">
```

Comment: `<item name="android:foreground">?android:attr/selectableItemBackground</item>` use this instead of your foreground if on Lollipop, on pre Lollipop declare a selector.

Comment: why was this question closed?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Please try this..

add `android:clickable="true"` and `android:focusable="true"` and 
change android:foreground to `android:foreground="?android:selectableItemBackground"`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="9dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="0.01dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:selectableItemBackground" >

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 1):

> in Recylerview.Adapter class use the following code,

```
@Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext);
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.additem, null);
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int itemPosition = recyclerview.getChildPosition(view);
                String item = list.get(itemPosition);
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.